# Why do old wood recorders sound and play better?

Tags: instruments, recorder, construction

I inherited a German-made soprano recorder that my mom bought in 1970.  She played it weekly in a senior citizen "fun band".  I pick it up occasionally and play it for a few minutes.

I have several other recorders including another wood soprano and an alto, which were also German made.  The difference in sound is incomparable.  The newer soprano has a whistle sound and is hard to play without squeaky tones.  The old one that my mom gave me sounds so much sweeter and plays almost effortlessly with no squeaky tones.  Is it just the age of the wood? Or were recorders made better 50 years ago?

Comment: While age of wood may have a minor impact, I doubt, whether the big difference you describe can be explained with this alone. Perhaps the recorders were in different leagues right from the beginning in respect to price? Also in Germany cheaper stuff is produced, even if now the beginner instruments will mostly come from Asia. I also remember, that even instruments of the same production batch may have significantly different quality, which is why one would try out several before choosing one.

Answer (score 2):

You can make good wooden recorders, you can make good plastic ones.  Or you can make less good ones - either wooden or plastic.   Sounds like your wooden German recorders are good ones!  It's not really about the wood as such.

Interesting how a country's 'brand' perception changes.  Not that long ago, 'Japanese' meant 'shoddy rip-off'.   Now, Yamaha are in the top league of musical instrument makers.   Then, a bit later, 'Sony' used to mean 'expensive, but quality'.  Sony still make some top-flight professional electronics, but their consumer stuff is as throw-away as anyone else's. And who but a fashion victim chooses an iPhone over a Samsung (or a cheap Nokia, if you just want a phone) now?

Comment: Given that both recorders mentioned in the question were made from wood, this answer is somewhat lacking.

Comment: Answer modified to address your point.  So you can remove your downvote?

Comment: You could have gone better into how recorders actually produce sound etc. But i still think the downvotes were unfair.

Comment: Wood or plastic, good or bad, they all produce sound in the same way!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is, above all, a question about manufacturing processes and quality control and active assurance.  Today many items including musical instruments are machined and manufactured to a very high reproductive quality at very affordable prices measured in the equivalent of human work hours.  But that means that competition between single exemplars essentially ends with the conclusion of prototyping.

With manual mass manufacture, the workers were competing mostly on execution rather than on design, but the highest paid workers were the finalizers and tuners and intoners, those responsible to complete the work by bringing out a coherent instrument.  They, in return, had feedback to the manufacturing stages happening before them and changes were fast to implement due to the flexibility of human workers.

Human adaptivity specifically comes into play for organic work materials like wood: a "feeling" for your work material and work piece allows to compensate for the natural variation of your raw material.  That is particularly important when wood becomes an active part of the resonator (like with acoustic string instruments), less so when it is essentially inert (like with solid body electric guitars or, well, recorders).

All that ends with the old pieces mostly under control of a single instrument maker have had a lot more potential for active intervention, human experience, and evolution of techniques leading to a robust process for producing quality pieces.  And the results will have a much larger variation of quality than modern methods, with the quality then competing in the market of demand and supply on a piece by piece basis.

For every great recorder of the past that is better than what you can buy nowadays, there are hundreds of quite worse recorders that got thrown away.  And all of them cost a lot more to make in terms of human work hours than even expensive new instruments.